# iptables: Only allow one IP address when rules are updated by other tools

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, docker, linux-networking

I'm learning about iptables and I want to set up a GNS3 (network emulation) host on a public IP and limit the access to only one IP address.

This one IP address should be able to connect with all protocols and ports.

Now from what I understand I'd usually go with an approach like this on a fresh host:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s X.X.X.X -j ACCEPT
```

But the GNS3 install already comes with rules from docker and I'm not sure if GNS3 itself dynamically sets rules for the QEMU VMs (because it's a network emulation). I think I can't just INPUT and FORWARD DROP here, because it would mess with the existing setup.

Now I want to make sure that my host is not open to the internet. How can I approach this securely? I think I can't use higher level firewalls (on the same host) because it would mess with iptables.

What's a good strategy here?

(This example shows a private IP address 10.11.12.160, the real host would have a public IP address instead)

**iptables -L**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LIBVIRT_INP  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LIBVIRT_FWX  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LIBVIRT_FWI  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LIBVIRT_FWO  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LIBVIRT_OUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain LIBVIRT_INP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:67

Chain LIBVIRT_OUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:68
```

**iptables -S**

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-N LIBVIRT_FWI
-N LIBVIRT_FWO
-N LIBVIRT_FWX
-N LIBVIRT_INP
-N LIBVIRT_OUT
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
```

**network config**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:8c:99:ec:54:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s18
    altname ens18
    inet 10.11.12.160/24 brd 10.11.12.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:9d:22:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:9d:22:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:12:b9:bb:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: When rules can be changed by other tools you are out of luck; whatever you do they can disrupt/disengage that. Either configure those other tools to not mess with your firewall or separate them into different containers/VMs/machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer in [the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/packet-filtering-firewalls/#restrict-connections-to-the-docker-host)

> Restrict connections to the Docker host

> By default, all external source IPs are allowed to connect to the Docker host. To allow only a specific IP or network to access the containers, insert a negated rule at the top of the `DOCKER-USER` filter chain. For example, the following rule restricts external access from all IP addresses except `192.168.1.1`:

> `iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ext_if ! -s 192.168.1.1 -j DROP`

> Please note that you will need to change `ext_if` to correspond with your host’s actual external interface. You could instead allow connections from a source subnet.